# How can I get these information(Organization information, user name, email address) from LDAP to Alfresco

Tags: ldap, alfresco

I can login to Alfresco using LDAP, but I couldn't get other information (e.g., Organization information, user name, email address...)
How can I get these information from LDAP to Alfresco?
Now, I'm using Alfresco Communnity Edition 5.0b

> C:\Alfresco\tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco\extension\subsystems\Authentication\ldap-ad\ad1\
>   ldap-authentication.properties

```
ldap.authentication.active=true
ldap.authentication.allowGuestLogin=false
ldap.authentication.userNameFormat=%sdomain.com
ldap.authentication.java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory
ldap.authentication.java.naming.provider.url=ldap://AD_IP:389
ldap.authentication.java.naming.security.authentication=simple
ldap.authentication.escapeCommasInBind=false
ldap.authentication.escapeCommasInUid=false
ldap.authentication.defaultAdministratorUserNames=Administrator
ldap.synchronization.active=true
ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.authentication=simple
ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.principal=alfresco 
ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.credentials=Alfresc0.
ldap.synchronization.queryBatchSize=1000      
ldap.synchronization.attributeBatchSize=1000
ldap.synchronization.groupQuery=(&(!(cn=00000)) (objectClass=group))
ldap.synchronization.groupDifferentialQuery=(&(objectclass=group)(!(whenChanged<={0})))                 
ldap.synchronization.personQuery=(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=512)))
ldap.synchronization.personDifferentialQuery=(&(objectClass=person)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=512) (!(modifyTimestamp<={0})))
ldap.synchronization.groupSearchBase=OU=Groups,dc=domaindc=COM 
ldap.synchronization.userSearchBase=OU=Users,dc=domain,dc=COM
ldap.synchronization.modifyTimestampAttributeName=whenChanged
ldap.synchronization.timestampFormat=yyyyMMddHHmmss'.0Z'
ldap.synchronization.userIdAttributeName=cn
ldap.synchronization.userLastNameAttributeName=sAMAccountName
ldap.synchronization.userEmailAttributeName=mail
ldap.synchronization.userOrganizationalIdAttributeName=physicaldeliveryofficename
ldap.authentication.java.naming.read.timeout=0
```

Comment: How the 'hell' can we now what you LDAP's userEmailAttributeName is defined? Go check with your LDAP administrator. Or download an LDAP-browser to check for yourself!

Comment: Are you sure you've defined the right LDAP properties for your directory to sync? Do you see the right values if you connect to your LDAP directory with an LDAP viewer tool and look at those attributes?